# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react

Eu estou realizando um projeto de um bootcamp e me deparei com esse problema.

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

A parte que está dando erro é essa:

```
service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    dispatch(setRestaurants(results));
}
```

E o componente inteiro é esse:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { GoogleApiWrapper, Map, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';

import { setRestaurants, setRestaurant } from '../../redux/modules/restaurants';

export const MapContainer = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { restaurants } = useSelector((state) => state.restaurants);
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const { google, query, placeId } = props;

  const searchByQuery = useCallback(
    (map, query) => {
      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      const request = {
        location: map.center,
        radius: '2000',
        type: ['restaurant'],
        query,
      };

      service.textSearch(request, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          dispatch(setRestaurants(results));
        }
      });
    },
    [google, dispatch]
  );

  const getRestaurantById = useCallback(
    (placeId) => {
      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      const request = {
        placeId,
        fields: ['name', 'opening_hours', 'formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number'],
      };

      service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          dispatch(setRestaurant(place));
        }
      });
    },
    [google, map, dispatch]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      searchByQuery(map, query);
    }
  }, [map, query, searchByQuery]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (placeId) {
      getRestaurantById(placeId);
    }
  }, [placeId, getRestaurantById]);

  const searchNearby = (map, center) => {
    const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    const request = {
      location: center,
      radius: '20000',
      type: ['restaurant'],
    };

    service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        dispatch(setRestaurants(results));
      }
    });
  };

  function onMapReady(_, map) {
    setMap(map);
    searchNearby(map, map.center);
  }

  return (
    <Map
      google={google}
      centerAroundCurrentLocation
      onReady={onMapReady}
      onRecenter={onMapReady}
      {...props}>
      {restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
        <Marker
          key={restaurant.place_id}
          name={restaurant.name}
          position={{
            lat: restaurant.geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: restaurant.geometry.location.lng(),
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </Map>
  );
};

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY,
  language: 'pt-BR',
})(MapContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Já tentei colocar dentro de um UseEffect, porém era necessário ele no onMapReady

Answer (score 0):

Provável que aqui neste bloco:

```js
service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    dispatch(setRestaurants(results));
}
```

O `service.nearbySearch()` tem um laço while que não acabe dentro dele, ou algo no seu código está sendo alterado em um luping infinito e renderizado na página...